# Am I required to make a move in solitaire

Tags: solitaire, klondike-solitaire

If I have an empty row in the tableau and I pull a King from the stock pile am I required to use it?

Reason for question:

1. I have a red King in one of the Tableau columns and red Queens are at the top of two other columns
2. I pull up another red King from the stock pile.
3. I'd prefer to keep the column open for a black King
4. Must I use the red King?

Answer (score 5):

You are never required to make a move in solitaire and every digital version I have played has never required any move.

Comment: Vegas on the other hand...

Comment: @Michael What about Vegas? Skipping those moves can hurt or help you depending on the deal.

Comment: Dunno, I played a version that had a "Vegas mode" once and if you couldn't or didn't move the game was over and you couldn't win any more from that deal.

Comment: @Michael That sounds like a variation of the game as it sounds like you are talking about a single version of a game in a specific mode. I have never seen that in an digital version of the game.

Answer (score 2):

No, playing is not mandatory in most versions of solitaire/Klondike.

See [these rules](https://www.thesprucecrafts.com/klondike-solitaire-card-game-rules-412473) (emphasis added):

> If the card you turn over is playable (either on a foundation or on the tableau), you **may** do so.

[These rules](https://howdoyouplayit.com/solitaire-rules-for-klondike-how-do-you-play-klondike-solitaire/) are make it even more explicit:

> When you cannot make, or do not wish to make, any further plays then you may draw from the stock pile.

[The rules on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klondike_(solitaire)#Rules) note that there exist versions of the rules where playing is mandatory. The presence of that note on one of the variations implies that play is not mandatory in the other variations where it is not noted:

> There are different ways of dealing the remainder of the deck from the stock to the waste, including the following:
>
> - Turning three cards at once to the waste, with no limit on passes through the deck.
> - Turning three cards at once to the waste, with three passes through the deck.
> - Turning one card at a time to the waste, with three passes through the deck.
> - Turning one card at a time to the waste with only a single pass through the deck, **and playing it if possible**.
> - Turning one card at a time to the waste, with no limit on passes through the deck.